# Can't get Select Image to open gallery in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, image, android-studio

I am following along this [youtube](http://youtube.com/watch?v=1AHzkfPacM0&list=PLam6bY5NszYN6-a1wt7yRISWfmYPdkbMu&index=6&t=746s) tutorial (up until the 12 minute mark). I have copied everything he did exactly, but even after Allowing permissions to use storage, clicking Add Image does not open any image directory or gallery location.

My issue may lie somewhere in my selectImage() or onRequestPermissionsResult() methods, but I am not getting any error messages so I'm not sure.

```
private void selectImage(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_SELECT_IMAGE);
        }
    }


@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_STORAGE_PERMISSION && grantResults.length > 0) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                selectImage();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Theres a chance of resolveActivity is resolving to null, try to just launch the intent, theres other intents that also works

Comment: Did you add the permission in mainfest as well?

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos Thanks, I took out the if statement for now and it works. I wonder why it returns null though. Do you have suggestions on how to troubleshoot that? This is my first time working in java.

Comment: @Zain I did! I have 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

and in <application> I have android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"